# Android ViewPager and TabLayout are not working fast

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

There are nested fragments with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Each fragment has listview inside it so they get call together and now I'm getting an issue of slow processing of app. I have tried some solutions like volley library but it didn't work for me. For more I'm posting my code too so please guide me to make it best.

MainTabFragment.java

```
public class MainTabFragment extends Fragment {

public static int position_child_tab = 0, three_childs_tab_position = 0;
static int count = -1;
int position_tab = 0;
Bundle args;
MyTabLayout myTabLayout;

public MainTabFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment MainTabFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static MainTabFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

    return new MainTabFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_fragment, container, false);
    myTabLayout = (MyTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainTabLayout);
    NonSiwpablePager pager = (NonSiwpablePager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    args = getArguments();
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("pos_next"))
        position_tab = args.getInt("pos_next");
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("pos_end"))
        position_child_tab = args.getInt("pos_end");
    if (position_child_tab != 3) {
        three_childs_tab_position = position_child_tab;
    } else {
        three_childs_tab_position = 0;
    }
    args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("pos_end", position_child_tab);
    ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter = getViewPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View customView = mAdapter.getCustomeView(getActivity(), i);
        myTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
    }
    pager.setCurrentItem(position_tab);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myTabLayout.getTabAt(position_tab).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
}

private ViewPagerAdapter getViewPagerAdapter() {
    ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    String title_arr[] = {"ADVISORY", "TOP ADVISORS", "EXPERT VIEW"};
    for (int i = 0; i < title_arr.length; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new Hashtable<>();
        map.put(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_TITLE, title_arr[i]);
        if (i == 0) {
            map.put(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_FRAGMENT, AdvisoryPagerFragment.newInstance());
        } else if (i == 1) {
            map.put(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_FRAGMENT, TopAdvisoryPagerFragment.newInstance());
        } else if (i == 2) {
            map.put(ViewPagerAdapter.KEY_FRAGMENT, ExperViewPagerFragment.newInstance());
        }
        mAdapter.addFragmentAndTitle(map);

    }
    return mAdapter;
}

public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "fragment_title";
    private static final String KEY_FRAGMENT = "fragment";
    boolean abc = false;
    private int[] drawables = new int[]{R.drawable.advisory_selector, R.drawable.top_advisors_selector, R.drawable.expertview_selector};
    private List<Map<String, Object>> maps = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public View getCustomeView(Context context, int pos) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_view, null);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ufonts.com_cambria.ttf"));
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        mImageView.setTag(pos);

        /*if(count >0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Count Is "+count,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mImageView =  (ImageView) mImageView.getTag(0);
            mImageView.setSelected(false);
        }
        */
        mImageView.setImageResource(drawables[pos]);
        mTextView.setText(getPageTitle(pos));
        return mView;
    }

    public void addFragmentAndTitle(Map<String, Object> map) {
        maps.add(map);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return (CharSequence) maps.get(position).get(KEY_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return (Fragment) maps.get(position).get(KEY_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return maps.size();
    }
}


}
```

Child Fragment of `MainTabFragment` is as :

AdvisoryPagerFragment.java

```
public class AdvisoryPagerFragment extends Fragment {
static String advisory_child_fragments[];
int myID = 0;
Bundle bundle;
TabLayout mTabLayout;

public AdvisoryPagerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment AdvisoryPagerFragment.
 */

public static AdvisoryPagerFragment newInstance() {
    return new AdvisoryPagerFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_pager, container, false);
    /*Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args  != null && args.containsKey("pos_end"))
         myID = args.getInt("pos_end");*/
    myID = MainTabFragment.position_child_tab;
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.fragmentTabLayout);
    advisory_child_fragments = new String[]{"EQUITY", "INDICES", "COMMODITY", "CURRENCY"};
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) inflate.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager);
    FragmentViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new FragmentViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View customView = mPagerAdapter.getCustomeView(getActivity(), i);
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
    }
    pager.setCurrentItem(myID);
    return inflate;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(myID).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
}

public static class FragmentViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public FragmentViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public View getCustomeView(Context context, int pos) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.belowTab_textview);
        mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ufonts.com_cambria.ttf"));
        mTextView.setText(getPageTitle(pos));
        return mView;
    }

    //
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return advisory_child_fragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new EquityFragment();
            case 1:
                return new IndicesFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CommodityFragment();
            case 3:
                return new CurrencyFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
 }
 }
```

And the child fragment of above `AdvisoryPagerFragment` is

EquityFragment.java

```
public class EquityFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
public static String imagepath = null;
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao1 = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static int count = 0;
static int count1 = 0;
ListView list;
View view;
Activity act;
AdvisorsAdapter adapter;
TextView empty_text;
private boolean isViewShown = false;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public static EquityFragment newInstance() {
    return new EquityFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.equity_activity, container, false);
    act = this.getActivity();
    Log.d("Callled ", "" + count);
    count++;
    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_equity);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    empty_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        if (catListDao.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 5);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do some work here
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //   if (!isViewShown) {
                            new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 5).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                            //    }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } else {
        CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
    }
 }
```

`FetchdataClass` which fetches the data from service and add into `ListView`

```
public class FetchAllData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int typeId;
    private Context cont;

    public FetchAllData(Context con, int typeId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cont = con;
        this.typeId = typeId;
        Log.d("Constructor Called", "yes");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getString();
    }

    private String getString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        URL obj = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            obj = new URL(Constants.AppBaseUrl + "/call_listing/" + typeId);
            String userPassword = "oi" + ":" + "kl";
            String header = "Basic " + new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");


            // For POST only - BEGIN
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            // For POST only - END

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Log.i("TAG", response.toString());
                return response.toString();


            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "POST request did not work.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (result != null) {
            //    pDialog.dismiss();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

                Log.d("Length ", "" + jsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    EquityDetails allDirectory = new EquityDetails();
                    allDirectory.setEntry_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entry"));
                    allDirectory.setSerial_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sl"));
                    allDirectory.setTg_value1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_1"));
                    allDirectory.setTg_value2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_2"));
                    allDirectory.setMainTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script"));
                    allDirectory.setMain_subTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("exchange"));
                    allDirectory.setRating_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rating"));
                    allDirectory.setReview_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("review"));
                    allDirectory.setImage1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("advisor_image"));
                    allDirectory.setPosted_by(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_by"));
                    allDirectory.setImage2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script_image"));
                    allDirectory.setCall_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("call_id"));
                    allDirectory.setBuy(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("buy_sentiment"));
                    allDirectory.setSell(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sell_sentiment"));
                    allDirectory.setRecommend(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("recommendation"));
                    allDirectory.setPosted_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_date"));
                    allDirectory.setExpiry_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("expiry_date"));
                    catListDao.add(allDirectory);
                }
                catListDao1 = catListDao;
                ab = true;
                adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 0);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


}
```

Comment: you can start your Asynctask in onstart it help to load data for fragment early and display data to use only when fragment is visible to user. for this you can use setuserhint visible method in fragment

Comment: I'm using `setUserVisibleHint` in each child Fragment but still it's not working.

Comment: @Singhak And I've tested it in `onResume` but it didn't work.

Comment: There is no on resume in fragment i think so use on start of fragment

Comment: I'm not updating code here till it gets a new change in it.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi use setMenuVisibility

Comment: What kind of performance issue we are talking about. Is it about UI thread being blocked (scroll lags?) or web Requests taking too long ?

Comment: Yes UI gets blocked but Now I have improved but issue is still not resolved. Now it takes so much time to change tabs if it's already opened and I try to change tab from `NavigationDrawer`

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Can you tell me how you have get this solved ? smooth scroll of tabs using view pager ??

Comment: Accepted answer is available.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Already tried with that but tabs are not scrolling smooth with that. as other answer is their what about `setMenuVisibility` how can i use it or what i have to add to this method  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to set

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_fragments or pages);
```

Do all your task in asyctask on creation of fragments

Answer (score 8):

I will suggest you to add the another method.

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);

    if (menuVisible) {
       Log.e("SetMenuVisibleFragmentA" , menuVisible + " ");
    }

}
```

> public void setMenuVisibility (boolean menuVisible)
>
> Set a hint for whether this fragment's menu should be visible. This is useful if you know that a fragment has been placed in your view hierarchy so that the user can not currently seen it, so any menu items it has should also not be shown.
>
> Parameters
>
> menuVisible :: The default is true, meaning the fragment's menu will be shown as usual. If false, the user will not see the menu.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi hmm.. so you want to make it smooth :/

Comment: @AnshulTyagi... i dont have that much experience so i can't help you.. sorry

Comment: Naah and I don't have so much time though

Answer (score 2):

Your

> onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1)"

in EquityFragment.java is weird. First of all, don't deactivate the
StrictMode (because you ignore the thrown "NetworkOnMainThread" Exception which is most likely the reason for your code to be slow...)

Then look at the else Part:

```
 } else {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do some work here
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   if (!isViewShown) {
                        new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 5).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        //    }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
}
```

You start a new Thread, where you should do your network stuff. Instead of doing it, you return to the ui thread (if you do network stuff here the app will hang") in your new thread and do it on the ui thread. (I don't know what exactly FetchAllData does).

```
} else {
    new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 5).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

should do the same Job.

In your FetchAllData class, you do all the JSON parsing in onPostExecute.
Do the parsing in doInBackground and only set the adapter in onPostExecute.

Comment: `FetchAllData` calls the web service and set data into `ListView`

Comment: Would be interesting to see the FatchAllData Class

Comment: you mean I should change only the part of `AsyncTask` ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do too much work in onPostExecute method.
Try to parse JSON and set data in background and notify the change in UIthread may be workable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the code from `OnActivityCreated()` to `onViewCreated()`.
2. Use `Gson` if Possible.(It had saved valuable seconds in my project.)
3. Post your adapters code if possible. If you are doing too many operation in `getView()` avoid it.
4. In your AsyncTask, you are using UI elements. I know we can access UI components in `onPostExecute()`, but try ro run that code on UI thread by using `runOnUIThread()`. It improves performance.