# click on tab layout doesn't work at all

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have implemented [this example](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/tablayout-with-viewpager-android.html).

but not able to click on 2nd tab.

my  xml  file  looks   like

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and    Main   activity

```
 pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    BuyCurrencyPagerAdapter adapter=new BuyCurrencyPagerAdapter(manager);

    //set Adapter to view pager
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
```

please give any suggestions.

Comment: Look at this question because it has each code what you're tying to do http://stackoverflow.com/q/34015117/2404262

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes I believe the problem might be that the ViewPager is positioned above the TabLayout. You want to place it below like this:

```
<AppBarLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

Comment: I had this issue where the ViewPager and AppBarLayout were placed in a RelativeLayout. Changing it to LinearLayout solve the issue.

Comment: I wasted hours to resolve this. Replaced module many times and searched a lot too but could not find solution but this simple fix of correcting position of viewpager and tablayout fixed it.  I was using relativelayout and it was just overlapping which was not visible by looking at it as fragment loaded was blank.

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE:** setOnTabSelectedListener deprecated, use addOnTabSelectedListener

Try this:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

});
```

If it's not working in your case, check your layout. May be there is a view overlapping your **TabLayout**.

Comment: worked for me with addOnTabSelectedListener() version of this.

Answer (score 0):

As this method is drepecatad now, you can use the new method

addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)