# Android - TabLayout Listener callbacks doesn't called

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I try to use create a tab layout like google play. But I couldn't catch click event. My code is below:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    Log.i("tag", " onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition());
                }
                .....
            });
        }
    });
```

onTabSelected never called.

**EDIT**

Below code work only swiping.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
     ...
}
```

**But I want to item click event**.

Comment: Why you added addOnTabSelectedListener in a Thread

Comment: Someone said that setupWithViewPager overrides onTabSelected. And I should set the listener after setupWithViewPager. I tried set after setupWithViewPager line, but it didin't work.

Comment: If you're using view pager then you can try addOnPageChangeListener method of viewpager

Comment: Please write addOnTabSelectedListener out of the thread and then try

Comment: @Parul I want to swipe using tab click event. Not swiping! These callbacks are triggered only swiping. I guess onTabSelected is not for this job.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a `Thread`.

Instead, try this:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           Log.i("tag", " onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition()); // return the position of the selected Tab

           Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() // this should show the clicked when selecting a tab
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This solution work only swiping slide. I want to a callback when I click the tab item. like TabLayout.Tab.onClick

Comment: It's actually the same I suppose. What do you see when you click on the Tabs? It should show the tab position **in the logcat** because we added: `Log.i("tag", " onTabSelected: " + tab.getPosition());` Instead, you can try adding a `Toast`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @us2956 it works for me too. 
tabSelectListener works with the selected tab and doesnt matter if its clicked or swiped

Comment: @MohamadRostami click event doesn't work for me. What is your device's api level? I use Android 8.1.0 and 6.0.1

Comment: @us2956 Perhaps you are using `setupWithViewPager`? Right? just set the adapte and then use my answer and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes I believe the problem might be that the ViewPager is
>   positioned above the TabLayout. You want to place it below like this:

[click on tab layout doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397381/click-on-tab-layout-doesnt-work-at-all)

Comment: This is exactly like my answer as well as said in the comments which you should remove setupViewPager..